# Failed to load HTTP resource xml parse in R

Tags: r, xml, http

I am trying to use COVID-19 api from URL below,
and at the last code, the error follows as:
**error 1: failed to load HTTP resource**

Is this a problem with my code, or the website's server problem?

```
apiURL <- "http://openapi.data.go.kr/openapi/service/rest/Covid19/getCovid19InfStateJson"
operation <- "Covid19InfStateJson"
api_key <- "apikey"
numOfRows <- 4
pageNo <- 1
startCreateDt <- 30
endCreateDt <- 30
url <- paste0(apiURL,
                            operation,
                            paste0("?api_key=",api_key),
                            paste0("&numOfRows=", numOfRows),
                            paste0("&pageNo=", pageNo),
                            paste0("&startCreateDt=", startCreateDt),
                            paste0("&endCreateDt=", endCreateDt))
                         
                        
library(XML)
xmlFile <- xmlParse(url)
```

Comment: Try `xmlParse(readLines(url), asText=TRUE)`

Comment: Please remove and regenerate your API key. Even though the URL is not in the question, the API key should never be made public.